# Javascript calls to a php webserver

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've got a huge problem in my app. I have got an application that connects to a php webservice and gets some data back when I press a button. The only problem is, my service isn't responding to me and I cant find out why.

I want to sent 'Windesheim' to my server, and the server (now hard coded) returns 'Windesheim'. I am not using the array for my test. I am using Google Chrome.

This is my .html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ekiden</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_Script.js"></script>       
</head>
<body>
    <input id="team" type="text"/><input id="button" type="button" value="Go" />

    <div id="feedback"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my .js:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
var team = $('#team').val();

$.POST('_Dataserver.php', {team: team }, function(data) {
    $('#feedback').text(data);
});
});
```

And this is my .php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$teams = array
(
"Windesheim"=>array
    (
        // Naam, Leeftijd, Tijd, Afstand, Gemiddelde snelheid
        1 => array ('Alfred', 20, 0, 0, 0),
        2 => array ('Willem', 36, 0, 0, 0),
        3 => array ('Michael', 22, 0, 0, 0),
        4 => array ('Stefan', 27, 0, 0, 0),
        5 => array ('Timmy', 20, 0, 0, 0),
        6 => array ('Pascal', 20, 0, 0, 0)
    ),
"Deltion"=>array
    (
        // Naam, Leeftijd, Tijd, Afstand, Gemiddelde snelheid
        1 => array ('Simon', 21, 0, 0, 0),
        2 => array ('Manuel', 33, 0, 0, 0),
        3 => array ('Stephan', 29, 0, 0, 0),
        4 => array ('Marko', 42, 0, 0, 0),
        5 => array ('Nick', 23, 0, 0, 0),
        6 => array ('Achmed', 20, 0, 0, 0)
    ),
"Landstede"=>array
    (
        // Naam, Leeftijd, Tijd, Afstand, Gemiddelde snelheid
        1 => array ('Patrick', 20, 0, 0, 0),
        2 => array ('Mohammed', 18, 0, 0, 0),
        3 => array ('Wilson', 19, 0, 0, 0),
        4 => array ('Walie', 22, 0, 0, 0),
        5 => array ('Marco', 52, 0, 0, 0),
        6 => array ('Mohabie', 45, 0, 0, 0)
    )
);

// Als er teams worden opgevraagd
if (isset($_POST['team'])) 
{
    $team = $_POST['team'];
    if($team == 'Windesheim')
    {
        //echo json_encode($teams[$team]);
        echo json_encode('Windesheim');
    }
}
// Als er niks wordt opgevraagd
else 
{
    echo '';
}

?>
```

Comment: How do you determine that "my service isn't responding"?

Comment: What does the console of your web browser say when you try this? Webkit's JS console gives really good info on AJAX requests and also allows you to track them in the network tab. Make sure that your server is actually being hit.

Comment: The output of `json_encode('Windesheim');` will not be a valid JSON text. JSON texts must have an object or array as the outer most layer, not a string.

Comment: The service does nothing, console isn't showing any error. If I press my butten there is nothing changing.

Comment: If I return echo 'Windesheim', it does also nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the code of _Scripts.js in a document.ready function.

Your code is executed before the DOM is rendered and thus
$('#button') returns no element.

_Scripts.js should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var team = $('#team').val();
    $.POST('_Dataserver.php', {team: team }, function(data) {
        $('#feedback').text(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: With this, I've got the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
 } has no method 'POST'

Comment: jQuery returns a Promise object, see the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

The above code is missing in your js code.

Also,

In PHP you are trying to check the value 'Windesheim' from the requested/post value,

```
if($team == 'Windesheim') {
    //echo json_encode($teams[$team]);
    echo json_encode('Windesheim');
}
```

But in JS you are passing the value is empty for team ID is in html input types value as,

```
<input id="team" type="text"/>
```

So its not printing/responding anything from client side php.

**To resolve please change value '' to 'Windesheim' in HTML**

(i.e)`<input id="team" type="text" value ="Windesheim"/>`

Comment: Don't I set the value when I filled in my input field and pressed the button?